# Including Omitted Record in NOT IN Condition

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring MVC Data project setup where I'm trying to select a list of users that don't already exist within an `Admin` table. Here's my repository method

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id NOT IN (SELECT a.id FROM Admin a WHERE a.id = :id) 
List<User>findAvailableUsers(@Param("id") Long id)
```

This works well, the more users I add to the `Admin` Table, the less I have available in my `<select>` tab

When it comes to **editing** an existing user in the `Admin` table, my `<select>` tag should contain all available Users to add as well as the currently mapped User, however because of the `NOT IN` clause this single user is omitted from the query results. Can I modify this query to include all available `User`s to add **including** the User that currently exists tag?

example: User 2 and User 4 have been added to the Admin table. When I edit the record for User 2 in that Admin table, I should still see User 2 as an available option, but it is omitted
[image]

Comment: When I edit the record for User 2 in that Admin table, I should still see User 2 as an available option, but it is omitted....here what do you mean by omitted.

Comment: omitted as in User 2 is not part of the result set because of the `NOT IN` Condition, but I want to include User 2

Comment: in your sub-query under not in just add one more condition that user should not equal to user2.

Comment: or even better, remove the whole subquery when you are trying to pull out data for the admin. (use a different query)

Comment: I agree with @JohnRuddell, this sounds like you are trying to use the query you use to find all users who aren't admins when you want to just see any user (for an edit procedure, not necessarily adding to admin), but that should be a different query anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id NOT IN (SELECT a.id FROM Admin a WHERE a.id = :id) OR u.id = :idToGet
```